# ms access vba unique table naming method datestamp

Tags: vba, timestamp, ms-access-2010, unique

I want to make the created table name unique, possibly by using hh:mm:ss in the table name so that if the macro is played time after time, it won't be telling me "table name already exists".

There are two parts to the query. One for creating the table, and one for refreshing access data objects so that the new table becomes visible.

```
  Sub SelectIntoX()

    Dim dbs As Database
       Set dbs = CurrentDb

    ' Part 1 Select all records in the scheme table
    ' and copy them into a new table
    dbs.Execute "SELECT * INTO " _
        & Format(Date, "yymmdd") & "_Scheme" & " FROM dbo_scheme;"

         'Part 2 refresh Access data objects to see new table appear
     DBEngine(0)(0).TableDefs.Refresh
     DoCmd.SelectObject acTable, Format(Date, "yymmdd") & "_Scheme", True

End Sub
```

The problem I have is that yymmdd is not unique and I am running it a lot each day.

I have also tried this hhmmss, but it only adds on zeroes.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be a good alternative:

```
Format(Now(), "yyyymmddhhmmss")
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately this doesn't work, as it only adds on zeroes.

Comment: Did you use the actual word `Now` or did you replace it with `Date`?

Comment: I was a fool. Thank you Marcucciboy2. I used Date instead of Now. Too many rum and cokes this weekend.

Comment: @DasalKalubowila Haha no worries, glad it helped